# Implementing breadcrumbs in Kohana framework

Tags: breadcrumbs, kohana-3.0

I want to include breadcrumbs on my Kohana website and would like to see a small snippet/example of implementation e.g Controller, View.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of using a session variable to which you keep appending the current page to the end of the list.  Then you simply show the last x entries of the session variable as the latest breadcrumb.  It's more of a recent history, but other than that you'll have to make something it yourself.